# Qual a melhor IDE para programar em AS2?

Tags: flash, ide, actionscript

Vou começar a programar numa aplicação em AS2 e gostaria de saber qual a melhor IDE a se usar.

Dei uma busca e achei essas duas:

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) e [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html).

Já trabalhei com o Android Studio que dizem ser bem parecido com o IntelliJ e era extremamente boa, boa mesmo.

**PS**: Futuramente essa aplicação será migrada pra HTML5 e Javascript, não sei se isso é valido de comentar.

Abraços.

Comment: Aconselho você usar o AS3. AS2 desde 2006 não é mais atualizado e o AS3 tem bem mais recursos. Inclusive o Flash Professional CC 2014 tem uma ferramenta de exportação para HTML5 nativo.

Comment: Mas é uma aplicação embarcada em AS2 impossivel de migrar pra AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sub>* Tanto a pergunta como a minha resposta podem ser baseadas em
>   opinião...</sub>

Atualmente existem alguns IDEs bem conhecidos, dentre os dois que você citou ainda existem os pagos [**Flash Professional**](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/flex.html) e [**Flash Builder**](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/flash-builder.html),  ambos da Adobe. O gratuito, mais conhecido e recomendável é o FlashDevelop, digo isso na quantidade de desenvolvedores (brasileiros) ativos que a comunidade possui, fóruns de ajuda e constantes atualizações da IDE em si, sem falar que a plataforma é parecida com o Flash Builder.

Não sei se vale à pena traçar linhas de códigos em ActionScript 2.0 para futuramente desenhar o conteúdo para Javascript. Embora parecidas, você perderá um tempo, certamente deverá alterar boa parte da programação. Sem dizer que muitas linhas do ActionScript 2.0 vão se perder em uma ou duas funções do Javascript, isso porque o mesmo já não é atualizado há um bom tempo, e a Adobe vem acompanhando as constantes atualizações com o SDK Flex, ActionScript 3.0 e o próprio Adobe AIR.

Procure ver a possibilidade de iniciar a aplicação com Javascript para tentar pular um certo tempo de programação para a aplicação. Hoje o Javascript já oferece bastante recursos para Web que são superiores ao Flash, como em desempenho e animações por exemplo. E frameworks muito bons.

Comment: Primeiramente, muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Então, sobre começar em Javascript, é algo que não temos escolha. O projeto já esta desenvolvido em AS2 e é uma aplicação embarcada que não aguenta mais que isso, o que impossibilida de migrar para AS3. 

Estamos desenvolvendo um aparelho melhor e com este, iremos ter o webkit para conseguir escrever o código em javascript e html5, qual será o meu trabalho. 

Mas enquanto isso não acontecer, terei que dar manutenção num código AS2 que nunca vi na vida, por isso a duvida da IDE. Mas muito obrigado, vou usar o flash builder então! Valeu, abraços